# Diabetes Type 1 : Why is glucagon helping for hypoglycemia?

Tags: diabetes, liver, glucose

first some facts (feel free to correct them):

- Glucagon is produced in the pancreas for both humans with and without diabetes type 1
- If a non-diabetes human has a hypoglycemia, the pancreas produces glucagon that builds glucose in the liver and gives it into the blood
- If a diabetic person (type 1) has a hypoglycemia that does not happen

So questions:

- Is there even glucagon produced for diabetic persons (type 1) in the pancreas?

  - If no, which sugar is used to stablize the glucose level in the blood?
  - If yes, why is it not used to regulate the glucose level and why does an external glucagon injection increase the glucose level (why is the liver stock not emptied)?

Thanks for all your answers (anything is appreciated)